# Facebook link to website logo

Tags: facebook

I have someone who wants to share my website through Facebook and they want my logo to appear in the FB post.  What do I have to do on the WordPress end to have my logo automatically appear in the FB post?

Comment: Please, check this previously posted answer at this link. [How do I get Facebook to show my site's logo when I paste the link in a post/status/comment?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10864240/6366593%20for%20the%20same%20question.)

Comment: @anass Thank you for this link. I did see it before but my inexperience with this rendered it Greek to me.  :)  I installed a plugin that added the required header info but it still isnt working on FB.  It does work from LinkedIn however.  Don't know why one works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out the following plugins:

- [Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/)
- [Open Graph Protocol Framework](https://wordpress.org/plugins/open-graph-protocol-framework/)

Either one will take care of all of the [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) metadata. Once you have the plugin set up, you can simply go to your homepage and you will see a "Featured Image" widget:

[image: Featured Image]

Pick your logo and you will see the `og:image` which is what Facebook uses to set the post image.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://web.site/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg" />
```

#### Update

I see that you set up the [Open Graph Protocol Framework](https://wordpress.org/plugins/open-graph-protocol-framework/) and now when I [visit your website](http://www.antolrx.com), I see the `og:image` metadata. Here's a preview of what it looks like if I were to share it on LinkedIn:

[image: LinkedIn Snippet]

Comment: Thank you!  Is it really that simple?  Why am I reading about having to do it with plugins and code, etc.?

Comment: @DLM Yes, because if you look at my example output, it gives `meta property="og:image"` which is a widely accept structure for all social sites nowadays, see more info from the [Open Graph protocol's website](http://ogp.me/). The places that you read about using a plugin/code may be dated.

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan Is this theme specific or does wp_head() handle it?

Comment: @TimMalone My apologies, the local copy that I have for testing has the [Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) plugin activate and didn't account for that. I'll update my answer

Comment: No probs, I thought it might be possible it was built in, but I hadn't come across that! Might also be worth adding some code options, should be fairly easy to hook a custom action in to do it too.

Comment: @TimMalone It would be a good idea for WordPress to have this feature built in. If I get around to it, I may take a shot of creating a custom function for it.

Comment: @DLM Updated my answer with one of two plugins that would help you. If you just want the Open Graph metadata, then go with the [Open Graph Protocol Framework](https://wordpress.org/plugins/open-graph-protocol-framework) plugin.

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan Thank you for the clarification on your answer.  I installed the Open Graph plugin and also set my Featured Image but I'm still not seeing the Logo (featured image) in the FB post.  Its only showing the website name and tagline with no image.  I am new at this so there may be something else I need to do that I am not aware of?

Comment: @DLM May you share the link to your site so I can analyze it?

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan   Yes thank you! its www.antolrx.com

Comment: @DLM I see that you were using a "coming soon" plugin, but not anymore. Now I see the `og:image` metadata and from doing a test on my end (LinkedIn) [I see your logo in the snippet](https://i.imgur.com/c9kYpxU.png).

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan  Yes I was using a coming soon page but changed it to see if that was the problem.  I tried again from FB and still do not see an image but I see that you do.   Until I can figure out what I am doing wrong on my end, does the Coming Soon page prevent the image from being displayed? http://imgur.com/haJ59Rl

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan I just tried it from LinkedIn and it did work for me. Is there FB specific code I need?

Comment: @DLM Nope, that's all on Facebook's end when you paste the URL. I don't have a Facebook to test the snippet, but it should work.

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan Ok. I did run it through the Sharing debugger and got some warnings.  I just don't know enough about this to make sense of it. I want to thank you for all your help you've given me.  It's given me a good start to understanding.  I'd buy you a beer if I could! :)